# Is there any option available to align the aspx source page tags in proper format

Tags: .net, tags, asp.net, html

Is there any option available to align the aspx page tags properly.and it should avoid empty lines in the source page.
I am spending my time on tags aligning.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "properly". What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I had lot of blank spaces between the asp tags..it makes my page long ...and my tags or not aligned properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In visual studio, you can use the auto format option. It works in aspx pages as well as code behind.

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>. Also accessible from the menu: Edit -> Advanced -> Format Document.

There is an additional command that will let you format the current selection:

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>. Also accessible from the menu: Edit -> Advanced -> Format Selection.